# Failed AppStore download

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I have tried to download an update from the AppStore for Yosemite 10.10.4 and unfortunately it interrupted.

Now I am in a situation where if I try the update again I get the following message:

`Some updates need to finish downloading before they are installed.`

If I confirm with `Download & Restart` it will tell me it is rebooting the computer but then  et another message saying:

`Available updates have changed`

If I confirm that one too it will just go back to the previous message.

It is some sort of infinite loop.

I have tried updating through the Terminal with:

`softwareupdate` command but the result is the same.

Comment: Check your versions of Pages, Number etc & make sure they're not updating in the background [look at Launchpad for the telltale thermometer] - mine updated to x.5.3 when I first tried updating to 10.10.4. If they are up to date, or at least not currently updating, then I'd get the combo updater & use that instead. - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your versions of Pages, Numbers & Keynote & make sure they're not updating in the background [look at Launchpad for the telltale thermometer] - mine updated to x.5.3 when I first tried updating to 10.10.4 & I had to wait until they were finished before the OS update would run.

If they are up to date, or at least not currently updating, then I'd get the combo updater & use that instead, from - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820